# Solr - Relative boost of sort and query

Tags: search, solr, lucene

My document is structured as the following -

```js
{
  "food_group":"Proteins",
  "carbs":"6.295",
  "protein":"13.729",
  "fat":"2.551",
  "calories":103.0
}
```

The aim is to fetch documents in an order determined by the boost of food_group which the user likes in the query as well as boost of proximity to calories preferred by user.

The boost based on food_group is acheived as follows-

```
(
food_group:"Proteins"^boost1  OR
food_group:"Dairy"^boost2  OR
food_group:"Grains"^boost3 
)
```

However the moment i add `abs(sub(preferred_calories,calories)) asc` to factor in the proximity of calories to preferred_calories of user the boost based on food_group is lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use boost function

```
bf=div(1,abs(sub(100,calories)))
defType=edismax
q=(food_group:"Proteins"^100 OR food_group:"Dairy" OR food_group:"Grains")
```

Source : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thebf(BoostFunctions)Parameter